# systemd service ssh-agent fails when stopped

Tags: systemd

I have a file called `~/.config/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service` with contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH key agent

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/ssh-agent.socket
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I can start the service and use the ssh-agent, but if I stop the service like `systemctl --user stop ssh-agent`, the service fails:

```
Dec 08 17:13:11 box systemd[571]: Stopping SSH key agent...
Dec 08 17:13:11 box systemd[571]: ssh-agent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Dec 08 17:13:11 box systemd[571]: ssh-agent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 08 17:13:11 box systemd[571]: Stopped SSH key agent.
```

The unit is marked as being in the "failed" state, I can't find out why. Setting `KillMode=none` makes the error disappear, but of course the agent is not killed. Any idea on what might be causing the failure? I've also tried setting `Type=forking` and removing the `-D` from the ssh-agent invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh-agent` quits with exit code 2 normally, see [here](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/a5ab499bd2644b4026596fc2cb24a744fa310666/ssh-agent.c#L1225). You can [prefix the ExecStart statement with a `-`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#id-1.8.3.6.2.4) to ignore the non-zero exit code.

`ExecStart=-/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not Failure but instead in your `systemctl --user status <svc>` output :

```
status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

And this error is coming from $SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable ; So there is an issue with the bind address, try to use the default one by deleting `-a ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}`and it will be gone.

Still the failed status will be there  and to get rid of it you have to implement a complete unit solution for stop and start because of the return code.

Comment: I saw the invalid argument code but I couldn't see its cause. I tried removing almost everything: `[Service]\nType=forking\nExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent`
and then if I do `ssh-agent -k` to kill manually, the `2/INVALIDARGUMENT` statement still appears in the log.

Comment: Oh. `ssh-agent -D`, then `SSH_AGENT_PID=<PID> ssh-agent -k`, the first process fails with code 2, nothing to do with systemd.